# is there a way to download a GLB file into a ArKit/RealityKit application?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I would like to have an application/module which can handle an URL of a 3D .glb file, download it to the file-system, and finally loads it as Entity and anchors it.

I think I have most of the code done, unfortunately I am facing issues with both .glb and .gltf files, the .usdz files loads as expected.

I have the same .glb file converted to .usdz added to Experience and I can load it from there in my application and perform some actions on it.

But my main aim is to be able to provide these same actions for the on opensea store .glb models also. In other words loading from Experience works, loading from url not for the same .glb file.

1. is there a way to load .glb and I am just missing something
2. can the .glb converted in application (I have found just a command line tool) to the .usdz ?

let me share my code:

```
import UIKit
import ARKit
import RealityKit
import Combine

class RealityViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var arView: ARView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        // Set up the ARView's session configuration for LiDAR scanning
        let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        if ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.supportsSceneReconstruction(.mesh) {
            config.sceneReconstruction = .mesh
        }
        
        // Enable horizontal and vertical plane detection
        config.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
        
        // Enable automatic environment texturing
        config.environmentTexturing = .automatic
        arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options = []
        arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert(.receivesLighting)
        arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert(.occlusion)
        arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert(.collision)
        arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert(.physics)
        
        arView.renderOptions = [.disableFaceMesh, .disableHDR, .disableMotionBlur, .disableCameraGrain, .disableDepthOfField]
        
        // Run the session with the configuration
        arView.session.run(config)
        
        // Set the frame of your ARView to cover the entire screen
        arView.frame = view.bounds
        
        // Add your ARView to the view hierarchy
        view.addSubview(arView)
        
        // Make sure ARView's autoresizingMask is set so it resizes with its parent view
        arView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    }
    
    
    func loadModel(from url: URL) {
        
        print("Checking file at \(url.absoluteString)")
        
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path) {
            print("File exists, loading model")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                do {
                    let entity = try Entity.load(contentsOf: URL(string: url.absoluteString)!)
                    if let anchorEntity = entity as? AnchorEntity {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.arView.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)
                            print("AnchorEntity anchored")
                        }
                    }else{
                        let anchor = AnchorEntity()
                        anchor.addChild(entity)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
                            print("ModelEntity anchored")
                        }
                    }
                    print("Finished loading")
                } catch {
                    print("Unable to load model: \(error)")
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("File does not exist, GLB download have failed")
        }
        
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct RealityKitView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    let url: URL
    var realityViewController = RealityViewController()
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> RealityViewController {
        
        print("makeUIViewController - realityViewController")
        return realityViewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: RealityViewController, context: Context) {}
    
    func loadModel() {
        print("loadModel")
        GLBManager.shared.downloadAndStoreGLB(from: url) { savedURL in
            if let savedURL = savedURL {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.realityViewController.loadModel(from: savedURL)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation

class GLBManager {
    
    static let shared = GLBManager()
    
    func downloadAndStoreGLB(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (URL?) -> Void) {
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { localURL, urlResponse, error in
            
            guard let localURL = localURL else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let fileName = url.lastPathComponent
                let cleanedFileName = fileName.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")
                let applicationSupportDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
                let savedURL = applicationSupportDirectory.appendingPathComponent(cleanedFileName)
            
                try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: localURL, to: savedURL)
                completion(savedURL)
            } catch {
                print("File error: \(error)")
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

```
//https://openseauserdata.com/files/1e23b556e07fb653bb538f8ffc2ba42d.glb
//https://openseauserdata.com/files/b1e1e80a7a2006598b20e3f01097c359.glb
//https://openseauserdata.com/files/f886842eb950813ba2f7ba775de327fc.glb

//WHEELS
//https://openseauserdata.com/files/afb49aede036bcb4f37f5785b88b9732.glb

//sample
//https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/blob/master/2.0/2CylinderEngine/glTF-Binary/2CylinderEngine.glb
//https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/blob/master/1.0/Avocado/glTF-Embedded/Avocado.gltf
//https://developer.apple.com/ar/photogrammetry/AirForce.usdz

struct RealityContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/quick-look/models/gramophone/gramophone.usdz") {
            let realityKitView = RealityKitView(url: url)
            realityKitView
                .onAppear {
                    realityKitView.loadModel()
                }
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

after a week of searching I have found out that the best solution for this approach would be a separate backend layer, which can store the USDZ, and prepare it beforehand, or with some lazy loading mechanism.

- you need an endpoint which returns you USDZ
- backend periodic job which checks the GLB collection and if there is a new one it downloads it and processes on the backend side.

[I would use this github](https://github.com/google/usd_from_gltf) repo for it

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating the backend layer, you could also download the glb/gltf and convert using [this](https://github.com/warrenm/GLTFKit2) converter and load in RealityKit based app.